# How can I translate this domain model into the desired front page

Tags: entities

I am quite new to Drupal and CMS alltogether and have some problems choosing the right way to setup my site to achieve my desired result. What I want to do is to create a page for my basketball club to read about upcoming games and practices and get some game reviews.

**Domain Model:**

[image: domain model]

So I have a team entity type which represents the different teams in my club. Each team has some reviews, games and standings associated to them.

I think about representing each entity type as a content type and setup the relationship by using entity references.

*Is this the common way to do this are is there another recommended way?*

**FrontPage:**

And now I want the front page to look like this ("conceptually"):

[image: Desired FrontPage layout]

I want a row for each team, containing the latest game review, the standings and the upcoming games. Of course I want only those related to the team to show up in the given row.

*And I honestly have no clou how to approach this? How would you do this?*

Best regards,
Marco

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). It can be set up to do exactly what you want. There are hundreds if not thousands of tutorials on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in using entity references. And you can implement it completely in views.

You can set the field display on an entity reference field to display the rendered referenced entity. You do this on the create content type display page. This might be the easiest route to go as it simplifies your view considerably. Now you only add your team type to the view and don't bother with the relationships at all as long as you select rendered entity as the output type.

You can go the fields route in views also. Team will be your base type for views, then you add relationships to the other three content types. You then add the required fields from all of the related content types, set their field display to none, add a global text field for each related type wherein you rewrite the content of the global text field and selectively include the fields you need. You then end up with three global text fields that each encapsulate only the fields of one related content type each.

You can also add a module or two. I would look at EVA and Display Suite. With both of them you are able to create a field on a content type (team) that can display the output of a view. You will then add three fields (one for each of the related content types) and three views that take the nid of the team as a contextual filter and return their respective results filtered thereon. The results can return rendered entities. Now you can reorder and format your fields using a specific view mode on the create content type display page.